# Is there no way to simply remove an element from the flow of the box model, eg remove its box while still allowing it to be displayed?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

I feel like there's something rather basic I'm missing here, which I previously thought I understood, yet it's not working how I feel it should and cannot figure out why/what I need to do.

If I need to draw a diagram I will, but this explanation should suffice. I have a main div which holds a large svg drawing. Within the div I'm trying to place a smaller div that is positioned relative to the div. The problem with this is that when I position the inner div (which has a fixed size) it pushes the svg drawing down because the div is of course set to display: block.

This is how I would expect it to work, but it seems there should be a way to disable this and from what I understand of css there is no way to do so short of floating the whole svg which would then complicate the whole design as the size of the div determines the size of the svg as it is now. Poor planning on my part perhaps to expect more out of css.

So is this what I'm going to have to do? Is there not a simple way to make something be neither block or inline effectively not computing it in the block model? I don't understand why this is not an option, it seems so basic. I'm also making use of the dojo toolkit if perhaps there's something in there that could help, and am open to including other libs so long as their not huge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the CSS `position:absolute` removes the element from flow. With no further positioning, the top left corner will be where it would have been anyhow. You will need to specify the width and heights, however.

Here is an example of SVG in HTML where the SVG is absolutely positioned, such that content above it does not move it:
http://phrogz.net/svg/constant-length-bezier.xhtml

Comment: But if I make it absolute it's then absolute to the window, no? I'd like to position it relative to the outer div. If nothing else that is still a lot more simple, I'd just have to lookup the position of the div everytime I want to reposition the inner div.

Comment: Fixed, magicalex filled in the gap for me, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's possibly worth pointing out that in order to position the inner div *relative* to the outer div, it's necessary to specify {position:relative} to the **outer** div as well as {position: absolute} to the **inner**, otherwise the inner div will be positioned relative to the body, or first ancestor with {position:relative}, unless no further position properties (top, left etc.) are set.

If you see what I mean.

Comment: Ah, I think combined with Phrogz that may answer my question completely, I'll give it a try after lunch.

Comment: Yup, it works! Wish I could give 2 right answers here.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `display: inline-block`. Not sure if that's the solution for your problem but worth a shot.